# Use bitwise operators in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, bit-manipulation, cypher, bitwise-operators

I'm a new to neo4j and cypher and I would like to know if it is possible to use bitwise operators in neo4j as explained at [this java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)?

because 
RETURN 5 AND 3
...fails

and so does
RETURN 5 & 1
or
RETURN 5 && 1

Thank you

Comment: What is your actual use-case? Perhaps you can solve it with an array of values?

Comment: Hi Michael, I want to pre-calculate if some node will have any of the desired items (among 50 or 60 possible ones) in any of its descendants. For instance, in a reduced version, precomputed value "011001" means that, among that node's descendants, you will find the second, third and sixth items. Then, if your are looking for nodes having the first or third item (desired="101000") you can speed the matching with WHERE precomputed & desired <> 0. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j does not support bitwise operations as a part of Cypher. Using the Java API you could perform your own bitwise operations using Java and manage that over your database transactions.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean like, for instance, "Findshortestpath"? Could you, please, point me to some example?